# Error while validating for Ubuntu 12.10 Kernel headers

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, kernel, headers

I have my VMware Player (v 5.0.0 build-812388) all up and running Ubuntu (12.10) from my Windows (Win 7) machine.

When I launch `sudo vmware-config-tools.pl`, it tries to search for kernel

```
Searching for a valid kernel header path...
The path "" is not a valid path to the 3.5.0-17-generic kernel headers.
Would you like to change it? [yes]

Enter the path to the kernel header files for the 3.5.0-17-generic kernel?
```

I entered `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic`.

```
The path "/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic" is not a valid path to the 
3.5.0-17-generic kernel headers.
```

Due to this it doesn't compile modules. So unable to mount HGFS (shared folder) filesystems.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have rebooted Ubuntu since applying any software updates. Software updates may change the kernel version.
2. Make sure you install `build-essential` package.
3. Try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Hi - I have installed build-essentials and also have installed headers thru sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r). rebooted ubuntu. then ran sudo vmware-config-tools.pl. It still gives the same error when provide /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic

Comment: nice job. worked a charm.

Comment: Still I am not able to get shared folder any idea why?

Comment: You're probably using a kernel that's too new for VMware. They only support old kernels without a patch to the VMware host and/or guest kernel modules. Almost every kernel version breaks the VMware modules in some way and they can't keep up.

Comment: @SatyamVakharia http://superuser.com/a/588307/144607

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same problem. I did all of the above and upgraded my installed packages.
sudo apt-get update&&sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo vmware-config-tools.pl was then able to automatically detect my kernel header files and completed its execution sucessfully. On reboot, I was able to see the HGFS mount and my shared folders.

Comment: I followed your steps too, but still not able to get shared folder ..
any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The path you entered is wrong. The right path is `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux`

See this post on AskUbuntu: [what-is-the-path-to-the-kernel-headers-so-I-can-install-vmware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40979/what-is-the-path-to-the-kernel-headers-so-i-can-install-vmware).

Comment: Can you consider moving the information from askubuntu across to avoid link rot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, note that `/usr/src/linux-headers`.... is not the kernel header vmware-config-tools is searching for, the real path is `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include`.

But yet it is better for the tool to find the path itself, so I recommend:

reboot your ubuntu and run all of these in sudo mode :

```
apt-get purge linux-headers-... (all versions you have installed already )

apt-get install --reinstall build-essential binutils

apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

then again run `/usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl` and hopefully it will find the path this time.