# No /mnt/hgfs in Ubuntu guest under VMWare Fusion

Tags: linux, macos, vmware-fusion

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 inside of VMware Fusion Pro 5. I have the virtual machine configured for read-only sharing of my home directory, but there's no /mnt/hgfs directory and there's no /etc/fstab line.

What can I do to mount my Mac home directory inside of the Ubuntu VM?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo vmware-config-tools`? Have you tried to reinstall the guest additions?

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue in 2023.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/hgfs
```

Use the above command first, followed by the following:

```
sudo /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other
```

I am using macOS and VMware Fusion with Ubuntu 18.x.

Comment: Worked for me on VM Workstation Player 15 running Guest OS : Ubuntu 18.04 and Host OS : Windows 10

Comment: Works on Kali too. Not permanent though. You need to mount on every restart. What makes it less annoying in Fusion is that you can just copy and paste files between host and guest, something you can't do in VirtualBox and therefore shared folders is a must.

Comment: This still required in VMWare Fusion Professional Version 12.2.5 (20904517) 2023

Answer (score 27):

For some reason, the auto-installed VMWare tools didn't do the job, but Ubuntu has a tool called vmware-hgfsmounter, if I installed it then I could do this:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
sudo mkdir /mnt/hgfs
sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /mnt/hgfs
```

After running these commands, /mnt/hgfs should now contain your shares.

Comment: It gives me error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device

Comment: Note: I only had to do the first line, accept all the defaults and reboot. Then it worked. (I already had vmware tools installed and shared folders was working until I updated 12.04 LTS yesterday).

Comment: sadly did not work on ubuntu 19 - but the suggestion to use vmgfs-fuse in laktak's answer did work (sudo /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other)

Answer (score 12):

For Ubuntu 16.04 I had to use `vmhgfs-fuse`, see https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/199#issuecomment-335525133:

> This impacts the Shared Folders client as we have switched from a kernel mode component to a FUSE file system component to provide the Shared Folders file system.
>
> This results in a new mount command to be used for creating the shared file system.
>   For Linux kernel versions we use the FUSE file system which will now mean you should be using the following command:

```
sudo /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18! If relevant I'm on a Mac Mojave Host and VMware Fusion Version 11.0.3

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, not being able to mount hgfs at all. I tried re-installing vmware-tools, then I tried installing vm-open-vm-tools and still no joy. I did notice that when I tried install open-vm-tools and reinstalling vm-ware-tools via vmware-install.pl, I got a failure notice for invalid gcc headers path. You can try this by installing vmware-tools without the -d switch for defaults. You will see the notice for the invalid path. I install headers with apt-get, you may or may not need to create a link to version.h. If version.h exists in /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/, skip that step.

> sudo apt-get install gcc make linux-headers-$(uname -r)
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname
> -r)/include/linux/

Installed the headers, I uninstalled open-vm-tools and reinstalled vmware tools using vmware-install.pl. This time hgfs was mounted correctly and my shared folder is there as well. Re-booted and it is still there.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question without realising that vmwaretools was actually failing to compile properly when I installed it. It seems to finish normally but actually has error messages, part of which look a little like this:

```
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-TRYAHr/vmhgfs-only/inode.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-TRYAHr/vmhgfs-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-38-generic'
make: *** [vmhgfs.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-TRYAHr/vmhgfs-only'
```

The solution I discovered is that vmware tools needs to be patched before it will compile successfully. This amazing repo has the answers:

https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches

Comment: The git-repo is really amazing, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading a VM from Kubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 I hit the same problem using VMware Fusion 5.0.3 on OS X 10.8.3.   Reinstalling VMware tools rebooting did not help.  Some issue between the VMware drivers and the new kernel I guess (my new kernel version is Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-19-generic).  I was able to access the shares using open-vm-tools as described in an answer by the OP but his last line has a typo and should read

```
sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /mnt/hgfs
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my last line to fix the typo. Note that Stack Overflow allows you to edit people's answers to fix these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the files directly to fix this issue. This is a bit of a pain, but the commands follow.

### vmhgfs

```
cd /vmware-tools-distrib/lib/modules/source
tar xf vmhgfs.tar
cd vmhgfs-only/
```

Open and edit `inode.c`. Edit line 888, change

```
result = compat_vmtruncate(inode, newSize);
```

to

```
result = 0;
```

Then save the file and exit the editor. Finally, tar it back up:

```
cd ..
rm -rf vmhgfs.tar
tar cf vmhgfs.tar vmhgfs-only/
rm -rf vmhgfs-only/
```

### vmci

```
cd ./lib/modules/source
tar -xvf vmci.tar.
```

Open and edit `./vmci-only/linux/driver.c`.

Edit line 127, change

```
.remove = __devexit_p(vmci_remove_device),
```

to

```
.remove = vmci_remove_device,
```

Edit line 1753, change

```
static init __devinit vmci_probe_device(struct pci_dev *pdev, const struct pci_device_id *id)
```

to

```
static int vmci_probe_device(struct pci_dev *pdev, const struct pci_device_id *id)
```

Edit line 1981, change

```
static void __devexit vmci_remove_device(struct pci_dev* pdev)
```

to

```
static void vmci_remove_device(struct pci_dev* pdev)
```

Close and save ./vmci-only/linux/driver.c. Then tar the files back up.

```
tar -cf vmci.tar vmci-only
```

Now you can run `./vmware-install.pl` and it should successfully install HGFS.

I needed to fix both of these broken modules to get HGFS working. Other sites report just needing to fix the vmhgfs module.

Sources:

HGFS: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/227866

VMCI: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2050666

Comment: As an FYI, this worked to get the /mnt/hgfs folder mounted, reading and writing. However I am getting segfaults when running commands like `python setup.py develop` (as an example,) so this is not a working solution. Note that I get the segfaults with `open-vm-tools` answer as well as the modified files per my answer. So something else is broken. I am going to open a new question on this topic soon.