# vmware does not install hgfs

Tags: linux, vmware, fedora, fedora-18

Here is the installation log that I have in Fedora 16:

```
The VMware Host-Guest Filesystem allows for shared folders between the host OS 
and the guest OS in a Fusion or Workstation virtual environment.  Do you wish 
to enable this feature? [yes] 

Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/linux/vmciKernelIf.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/common/vmciDriver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/common/vmciResource.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/common/vmciRoute.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/common/vmciContext.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/common/vmciDatagram.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/common/vmciHashtable.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/common/vmciEvent.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/common/vmciQueuePair.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/common/vmciQPair.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/common/vmciDoorbell.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/driverLog.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/vmci.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/vmci.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only/vmci.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only'
cp -f vmci.ko ./../vmci.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmci-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/message.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/rpcout.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/cpName.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/link.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/request.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/stubs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/tcp.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/hgfsEscape.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/file.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/bdhandler.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/transport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/inode.o
/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/inode.c: In function ‘HgfsPermission’:
/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:1755:8: warning: ‘dentry’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:1813:22: note: ‘dentry’ was declared here
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/super.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/vmci.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/dir.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/fsutil.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/cpNameLinux.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/hgfsBd.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/backdoorGcc64.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/module.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/page.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/backdoor.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/dentry.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/cpNameLite.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/kernelStubsLinux.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/vmhgfs.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/vmhgfs.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only/vmhgfs.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only'
cp -f vmhgfs.ko ./../vmhgfs.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-8X1GaP/vmhgfs-only'

Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-SN1mhC/vmxnet-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SN1mhC/vmxnet-only/vmxnet.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-SN1mhC/vmxnet-only/vmxnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SN1mhC/vmxnet-only/vmxnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.6.11-4.fc16.x86_64'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-SN1mhC/vmxnet-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-SN1mhC/vmxnet-only'
cp -f vmxnet.ko ./../vmxnet.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-SN1mhC/vmxnet-only'

The vmblock enables dragging or copying files between host and guest in a 
Fusion or Workstation virtual environment.  Do you wish to enable this feature?
[yes] 

!!! [EXPERIMENTAL] !!!
VMware automatic kernel modules enables automatic building and installation of
VMware kernel modules at boot that are not already present.  By selecting yes,
you will be enabling this experimental feature.  You can always disable this
feature by re-running vmware-config-tools.pl.

Would you like to enable VMware automatic kernel modules?
[no] 

Thinprint provides driver-free printing. Do you wish to enable this feature? 
[no] 


Disabling timer-based audio scheduling in pulseaudio.



Detected X server version 1.11.4



Distribution provided drivers for Xorg X server are used.

Skipping X configuration because X drivers are not included.

Creating a new initrd boot image for the kernel.
   Starting Virtual Printing daemon:                                   done
Starting vmware-tools (via systemctl):                     [  OK  ]
The configuration of VMware Tools 9.2.3 build-1031360 for Linux for this 
running kernel completed successfully.
```

Please note that there is a question" The VMware Host-Guest Filesystem allows for shared folders [yes] ", then hgfs.ko is installed and then vmxnet.ko installation follows normally.

Here is a log that i get in Fedora 18

```
The VMware Host-Guest Filesystem allows for shared folders between the host OS
and the guest OS in a Fusion or Workstation virtual environment.  Do you wish
to enable this feature? [yes]

Before you can compile modules, you need to have the following installed...
make                                                                                                 gcc                                                                                                                                                          
kernel headers of the running kernel                                                                                                                        


Searching for GCC...
Detected GCC binary at "/bin/gcc".
The path "/bin/gcc" appears to be a valid path to the gcc binary.
Would you like to change it? [no]
Searching for a valid kernel header path...
Detected the kernel headers at
"/lib/modules/3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64/build/include".
The path "/lib/modules/3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64/build/include" appears to be a
valid path to the 3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64 kernel headers.
Would you like to change it? [no]
make: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-jub19n/vmxnet-only'
/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-jub19n/vmxnet-only/vmxnet.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-jub19n/vmxnet-only/vmxnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-jub19n/vmxnet-only/vmxnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.9.4-200.fc18.x86_64'
/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/modconfig-jub19n/vmxnet-only'
make[1]: `postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-jub19n/vmxnet-only'
cp -f vmxnet.ko ./../vmxnet.o
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-jub19n/vmxnet-only'

The vmblock enables dragging or copying files between host and guest in a
Fusion or Workstation virtual environment.  Do you wish to enable this feature?
[yes]
!!! [EXPERIMENTAL] !!!
VMware automatic kernel modules enables automatic building and installation of
VMware kernel modules at boot that are not already present.  By selecting yes,
you will be enabling this experimental feature.  You can always disable this
feature by re-running vmware-config-tools.pl.

Would you like to enable VMware automatic kernel modules?
[no]
Thinprint provides driver-free printing. Do you wish to enable this feature?
[no]

Disabling timer-based audio scheduling in pulseaudio.
Detected X server version 1.13.3
Distribution provided drivers for Xorg X server are used.
Skipping X configuration because X drivers are not included.

Creating a new initrd boot image for the kernel.
   Starting Virtual Printing daemon:                                   done
Starting vmware-tools (via systemctl):                     [  OK  ]
The configuration of VMware Tools 9.2.3 build-1031360 for Linux for this
running kernel completed successfully.
```

I also tried [open-vm-tools recipie](https://superuser.com/a/588307/110460). But,

```
[root@localhost Documents]# mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /mnt/hgfs
Error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device
```

I do not know where is the vm-tools support site.

**update**

I have checked and vmxnet3 is installed by `configure_module('vmxnet3')` in `vmware-config-tools.pl`. It does not reach `configure_module('vmhgfs')` because

```
     # vmhgfs now depends on vmci.  Check to ensure it's configured.
     if (defined(db_get_answer_if_exists('VMCI_CONFED')) &&
         db_get_answer('VMCI_CONFED') ne 'yes') {
        return 1;
     }
```

silently "protects" the call from our needs. I can say that `db_get_answer_if_exists('VMCI_CONFED')) = 1, db_get_answer('VMCI_CONFED') = 'no'` and warning

> The module vmci has already been installed on this system by another
>   installer  or package and will not be modified by this installer.  Use
>   the flag 
>   --clobber-kernel-modules=vmci to override.

in the log above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting the `vmware-config-tools.pl` with vmci override flag,

```
vmware-config-tools.pl  --clobber-kernel-modules=vmci
```

The problem has gone. Now, I'm getting another

```
/modconfig-o4Yd7O/vmhgfs-only/inode.c: In function ‘HgfsTruncatePages’:
/tmp/modconfig-o4Yd7O/vmhgfs-only/inode.c:888:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘vmtruncate’
```

error. But, it is another issue and I see it (yet, I have fixed it also with help of [this patch](http://erikbryantology.blogspot.com/2013/03/patching-vmware-tools-in-fedora-18.html?showComment=1371065680656#c7835140221648192665) ).